# Finding a removable singularity

Tags: equation-solving, discontinuity

I have more complex functions than this, but say I just have:

```
f[x_]:=(x-a)/(x-2)
```

The function is not defined for `x==2`. I would like to find the value of the parameter `a`, so that I have only a removable discontinuity there, and not an essential (or infinite) one. Clearly, for this simple example, I want `a` to equal 2. I searched around quite a bit, but came up empty-handed.

My first thought was to require that the two one-sided limits would equal each other, i.e.:

```
Reduce[Limit[f[x], x -> 2, Direction -> "FromBelow"] ==
    Limit[f[x], x -> 2, Direction -> "FromAbove"], {a}, Reals]
```

however the result is:

```
Reduce::infc: The system (-2+a) ∞ == (-2+a) (-∞) contains
    an infinite object ∞.
```

The problem results from the fact that the `Limit[]`s happen before `Reduce[]` gets a chance to try out various values of `a`. At this point, I *could* cheat, replacing the ∞ with 1 and -∞ with -1, and then feed it to `Reduce[]`. But, that would be cheating, and also would only work for this specific case. `FindInstance[]` was no further help.

`NLimit[]` (with `Chop[]` if necessary) from the `NumericalCalculus` package would not work, as it requires the function to be numeric -- not the case here with the parameter `a`.

Moving on, I thought of going back to the definition of a limit. The following is shamelessly (shamefully?) snarfed and adjusted from the "Neat Example" at the end of the [Reduce reference page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html?view=all):

```
Reduce[ForAll[ϵ, ϵ > 0,
    Exists[δ, δ > 0,
    ForAll[x, Element[x | a, Reals] && 0 < x - 2 < δ,
    RealAbs[f[x] - f[4 - x]] < ϵ]]], a]
```

(Trust me, it looks a *lot* nicer with all of the Greek characters and mathematical symbols in there. :-) )

This nicely did the job, producing: `a==2`. This even worked for a (only slightly?) more complex:

```
g[x_] := f[x]^4 - f[x]^2 + 1
```

However, it did *not* work for:

```
h[x_] := Sin[f[x]]
```

So, my question is: does anyone have an idea how to get this to work for more general functions with parameters, with either of the above forms of `Reduce[]`, or perhaps another approach?

Thank you all for your time and ideas.

Answer (score 4):

You could do a series expansion, find all the poles, and set them to 0. Here is a function that does this:

```
removable[expr_, x_->v_, param_] := Module[{poles},
    poles = Cases[
        Series[expr, {x, v, -1}],
        HoldPattern@SeriesData[a__, max_, 1] :> SeriesData[a, 0, 1][[3]],
        {0, -1}
    ];
    Solve[Flatten @ poles == 0, param]
]
```

For your examples:

```
removable[(x-a)/(x-2), x->2, a]
removable[((x-a)/(x-2))^4-((x-a)/(x-2))^2+1, x->2, a]
removable[Sin[(x-a)/(x-2)], x->2, a]
```

> {{a -> 2}}
>
> {{a -> 2}}
>
> {{a -> 2}}

A slightly more complicated example:

```
removable[(x^2-a x-2a^2)/(x-2) + Sin[(x-b^2)/(x-2)], x -> 2, {a, b}]
```

> {{a -> -2, b -> -Sqrt[2]}, {a -> 1, b -> -Sqrt[2]}, {a -> -2, 
>     b -> Sqrt[2]}, {a -> 1, b -> Sqrt[2]}}

Comment: Carl, thank you very much for this answer. I should have pointed out that I am teaching Calculus I, and therefore would like to stick to the relevant Calculus I mathematics of limits and continuity. In other words, I would like to solve this problem with more *Mathematica*, rather than more *mathematics*. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

One way to find the location of the discontinuities is to find the domain of the function. For your example, this gives:

```
f[x_] := (x - a)/(x - 2);
FunctionDomain[f[x], x]
x < 2 || x > 2
```

This also works for your other examples:

```
g[x_] := f[x]^4 - f[x]^2 + 1;
h[x_] := Sin[f[x]];
{FunctionDomain[g[x], x], FunctionDomain[h[x], x]}
{x < 2 || x > 2, x < 2 || x > 2}
```

Comment: I think the OP wanted to extract the value of `a`, not the location of the discontinuity. They aren't necessarily the same thing, e.g., `(x-a-1)/(x-2)`

Comment: Carl, thank you for pointing this out. Sorry if I was not clear enough.